# TabWidget flickers when keyboard hides android

Tags: java, android, tabbar

How to hide a tab bar at bottom. 
I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`. I do not get the desired result.  I also added the event bus and when the focus on the edit text disappears tab bar:

```
public void showTabBar()
{
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 

public void hideTabBar()
{
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But, it flickers, too, is not suitable. What else can I do?
[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [cs629227.vk.me](http://cs629227.vk.me/v629227103/2349b/Aqahsx2XO68.jpg))</sub>

Comment: How did you fix it?